# How to solve memory leak in react native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, memory-leaks, expo

everyone.
I'm building a react native app on an expo bare workflow. The app does not make any api calls, but have a lot of animations, screens and audio.

Tools used:

- Animations - React Reanimated 3;
- Screens - React Navigation;
- Audios - Expo AV;

Everything works fine, but in a certain point it crashes.
Monitor memory usage in Debug Monitor in XCode I noticed memory usage increase on every screen change. I refactored React code using React.memo, useCallback and useMemo, but with no effect on memory increment. So I suggest that the crash issue is memory leak.
Does anybody know how to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a git repo you could maybe share it?

Comment: Hi, @JamesG. Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I can't provide repository. Instead I can show my package.json if it can be useful.

Comment: Have you found a way to profile the memory? I mean, did you find out where this memory was going, and how did you find out?